# charmap can't decode byte 0x8d

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x, codec

I'm trying to create an APK from a C++ code with Cocos Framework (cocos2d-x 3.8.1)

When i go in the directory and use the command line "cocos run -p android", i got an error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position
>   29180: character maps to undefined

This happen when the following line is called

```
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
```

in the file

> "\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23

Any idea about how to fix this ?

Comment: 0x8D is not an ascii character. Where is 0x8D coming from? and what is decoding_table?

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d requires Python 2.7 to run. You are getting that error because of your Python version (Which is the 3.5v).

That command is going to search for the python.exe from your Python directory.

I suggest you to download the 2.7 version and rename the python.exe to python3.exe in your "Python\Python35-32" directory, so that the Python2.7\python.exe is run. This works to me.

Comment: I changed Cocos path variable so Python2.7 is run instead of Python3.5. Now i got an error telling me that ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is not defined in the environment, no matter how much i try to put it in the path variables...

Comment: Well, if you are on Windows, create that global variable called ANDROID_SDK_ROOT pointing to you C:\Android\android-sdk. And DON'T forget to reboot your OS to apply those changes.

Comment: Ah you're right, i didn't reboot. Now it works better, but NDK_ROOT is not found. I'll create the according PATH variable.